# Can the group administrator set the notification level for its Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Is it only the members of the group, which can set how often they will get notification from a group? Can the administrator of a group adjust this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not change notification setting for group members. You can change only for yourself. Only group members can change the group notification for their self.

Answer (score 0):

No, Administrators can only adjust their own personal preferences.

To edit your notification settings for a group, go to a group and click Notifications in the top right corner.

From here, you can select:

- All Posts: You'll get notifications any time members post in the group
- Highlights: You'll get notifications for suggested posts and posts from your friends
- Friends' Posts: You'll get notifications whenever your friends post
  Off: You won't get notifications when members post

Note: If a group you're in reaches 250 members or more, its notification setting will be set to Highlights by default. This setting can be changed later.

https://www.facebook.com/help/187225274663021

Comment: I see, but you describe changing the notifications that I get. Can I set how often the members of my group get the notifications?

Comment: So it is not possible for administrators to change the notification level?

Comment: No it's not possible for admins to change notification for other users. I read your original question as you wanting to update your notifications as an admin to change how often you see notices about your group.